# Why am I unable to add new version for TestFlight external testing?

Tags: testflight, xcode7.2, ios9.2

I have an app that I have out for external testing; I have submitted two (2) different versions without any problems.  Now, I am trying to submit another new version (#3), but when filling out the Test Flight Information the "next" button is disabled, preventing me from adding the new version.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?  or what the problem is?

Comment: My answer about the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784478/apple-testfiight-app-submission-cant-click-next/35793166#35793166

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem and finally got it working. First I had to go into safari, Chrome didn't work. You have to fill out every field for every language you have. Every. Single. One.

Then the next button finally became active.

Also the app description has to be over 10 characters long.

I'm submitting a bug report to apple because whoever made this was an idiot.

Comment: That works for *most* languages: French and German excepted!  I am so frustrated!

Comment: I just submitted  RADAR #24917060

Comment: @SpokaneDude I am super frustrated too. I've spent hours now fighting with idiotic apple stuff

Answer (score 0):

I filled out everything, but still no Continue button gets activated. For some languages email and url field will appear for some not. I think something is really badly programmed there

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround:

1. go to TestFlight for your app using Safari.
2. enter all of the data for all of your supported languages; it doesn't have to be in *the* language (I used English for all of the languages, French, German, Japanese, etc).  Just make sure you are mindful of the length restrictions!
3. Next button is then enabled! And you can continue on... :D

Answer (score 0):

read this news on the dashboard iTunes connect

> TestFlight Requires Export Compliance Information
>   All TestFlight builds now require Export Compliance information. To answer Export Compliance questions and upload any necessary documentation, visit the new Encryption section in Features. Once your documentation is approved, you will receive a key string value to add to your build's Info.plist. Learn more in Resources and Help

in short, if your application has not put that in your encryption info.plist, can also resolve:

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>
```