# Apple Testfiight App Submission Can't Click Next

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I submitted my TestFlight build, and not I'm trying to select it for external testing.  I've done this with the prior beta version, and with several other apps.

The problem is I can't click the Next button.  All the fields are clearly populated.  Also of note, when this happened yesterday there were Support and Marketing fields.  Today (for English) they are not there.

Anyone else ever experience this?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Hello my dear friend there,

I am also having your issue this morning. After several trials and errors, I found that turn out the next button greyed out just because we have to fill all description field needed for all languages we choose.

Pictures below will explain this:

1. So you have filled all of those needed descriptions. Then you have to notice that you can select language in this dropdown button

[image: First Picture]

3. Picture above explains that I have two language localized, Indonesian and Indonesian. May be different in your version, try to change the language with another your localized language. Those descriptions that you have filled is becoming **blank again**! And needed to be **filled again**!

[image: Second Picture]

Fill all of those descriptions, than the next button should be **clear** and **clickable**!

So the problem is we are not familiar yet with this new Test Flight's select build screen and C'mon Apple, I thought you are the best man in earth about User Experience.

**Update:**

I think finally Apple realize this lack of User Experience, they added a notification to complete all required fields for each localization so that we can click **next**.
[image: Apple realize their mistake]

Comment: Thank you Muhammad, this was the solution.

Comment: You're welcome mate. Could you upvote or accept my answer? I need the reputation btw :P

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with only one app language. Turning off the stylesheet and setting the "Have you made any significant changes to this build since your previous submission?" phrase to yes/no made the most likely broken code on that page working again - after you reenabled the stylesheet.

It's definitely Apple's fault.