# Submitting for beta review issues

Tags: app-store-connect, plist, beta-testing

So last week Apple changed they way they want us to verify our use of encryption. Now, it is loaded into the `info.plist` folder. 
I only use encryption for simple verification so added

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>
```

into my `info.plist` (I am confident this is correct).

After uploading the build to `iTunes` connect and it finishing processing I am able to select my new version however the `next` button is blanked out:

[image]

I've been banging my head against my desk for a week and trying everything....anyone any ideas of things to check/things to do??

Comment: May be my answer here related with your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784478/apple-testfiight-app-submission-cant-click-next/35793166#35793166

Comment: brilliant - thank you!!!