# Cannot press "next" button on TestFlight external test

Tags: ios, testflight, beta-testing

On TestFlight External Testing, I went as follows, but I could not proceed further because "Next" button was diabled.

1) Added Build to Test

2) Selected build to test

3) Input "What to test" & "Beta App Description"

Any idea how to enable the "Next" button?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried switching between fields?

Comment: This might be a temporary error with Apple Server. I also encountered the same issue in the past and the issue was solved after 2 days.

Comment: Sometimes you must scroll to end of agreement.

Comment: See my answer about same issue here and you will be OK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784478/apple-testfiight-app-submission-cant-click-next/35793166#35793166

Comment: Thanks, guys for comments. I tried switching languages but could not press next button still.

I solved it as below:
1)  Go to build list (TestFlight Builds > iOS) 2) Choose newly uploaded version 3) Fill in all fields 4) Gp back to external testing 5) Select the version 6) Fill in the form 7) Next button got enabled!

Comment: Another weird hack around is to disable the stylesheet on the page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35873504/194585

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it as below:

1. Go to build list (TestFlight Builds > iOS)
2. Choose newly uploaded version
3. Fill in all fields
4. Go back to external testing
5. Select the version
6. Fill in the form
7. Next button got enabled!